# UI still freezes when the long operation is defined using IExecutor

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin.android

I want to add 1500 views to a `LinearLayout` in `Xamarin.Android`. Since adding this large a number of views will freeze UI, I tried to add first 20 views in the UI thread and add the rest of the views in a separate thread using `IExecutorService`. But still the UI stays frozen until the 1480 iterations I have added in the `IRunnable.Run` method complete. Why the UI freezes since I defined the long operation in a separate thread?

Below is my code in C#

```
    internal class LinearLayoutEx : LinearLayout, IDisposable
    {
        IExecutorService exec;
        MyRunnable runnable;
        internal LinearLayoutEx(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            runnable = new MyRunnable(this);
            exec = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                //20 views are being added to the LinearLayout
            }

     exec.Execute(runnable);
        }
     }

    internal class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
    {
        internal LinearLayoutEx linearLayout; 
        private MyHandler myHandler;
        internal MyRunnable(LinearLayoutEx ll)
        {
            myHandler = new MyHandler(Looper.MainLooper);
            linearLayout = ll;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Message msg = myHandler.ObtainMessage(1, linearLayout);
            msg.SendToTarget();
        }
    }

    internal class MyHandler : Handler
    {
        LinearLayoutEx linearLayout; 
        internal MyHandler(Looper looper):base(looper)
        {

        }

        public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            linearLayout = msg.Obj as LinearLayoutEx;
            for(int i = 20; i < 1500; i++)
            {
                //1480 views are being added to the LinearLayout
            }

            base.HandleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a separate thread for long operations. Either a new thread or an AsyncTask should do the trick (I haven't used xamarin before, so I have no clue what the equivalent is there)

Comment: @Zoe - Thanks. I think AsyncTask will update the UI only once when the long operation is completed. But I want to add the child view to the LinearLayout at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It doesn't automatically update anything. After an iteration you just use `runOnUiThread` and add the data. (runOnUiThread does exactly what you'd expect: a method for running code on the UI thread, that allows you to update the view from the asynctask while it is in the background)

Comment: I can't use runOnUiThread. Because my code is part of a class library. I can't get  access to activities :(

Comment: Pass an activity instance then. The method is public so you need any instance.

Comment: I can't do that. The main application is going to be developed by the user. The user cannot be expected to pass an Activity instance to the library.

Comment: Pass it to the method. Otherwise you will get ANR's. Your choice in the end, but either you live with freezing app or you pass an activity instance and use a separate thread and runOnUiThread

Comment: Do you mind if using control like `RecyclerView` to load images?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT - I have not used `RecyclerView` before. Actually, the purpose of the above code is to display images that can be scrolled, zoomed in and out like a PDF document viewer. I will finally add the `LinearLayout` to a `ScrollView`. Can I achieve this using `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: @NavaneethaKannan, yes you can, and the ui virtualization issue may also be resolved.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thanks for the suggestion. Now I am using `RecyclerView` and it loads the child Views almost instantly no matter how many they are. As I mentioned before I want to create a PDF reader. The vertical scrolling is provided by the `RecyclerView`. But when the reader is zoomed in, the pages will become wider than the view port. Then I should be able to scroll horizontally. In practice, `RecyclerView` should not be placed inside a `ScrollView`or other scrollable Views. I would appreciate if you have any suggestions on how can I achieve horizontal scroll when the reader is zoomed in.

Comment: @NavaneethaKannan, then you need to know how to custom item view for `RecyclerView`. And I think it's a new question which is followed to this, if it possible, can I write an answer here about `RecyclerView` and you create a new thread to ask about how to make image scrollable inside `RecyclerView` with your current code?